# Как определить в каком месте находиться объекты и куда можно пройти?

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет! Делаю игру , где персонаж ходит по лабиринту (по сетке) , у лабиринта есть стены и я ломаю голову не зная как узнать есть ли впереди игрока стена , может ли он туда пройти или нет . Была идея на все стены навесить скрипт находящий дистанцию от стены и игрока и если игрок находиться около стены , то запрещать ему двигаться в ту сторону , но я не придумал как можно взаимодействовать со стенами , я хотел навесить на них коллайдеры и в коде при взаимодействии с коллайдером проверять дистанцию , после чего запрещать двигаться в сторону стены при определённой дистанции , но вот только как понять на какой оси находиться стена что бы уже в коде запретить движение в ту сторону .
Возможно есть другой способ решить мою проблему , да и вообще моя идея очень муторная , ведь нужно будет при создание нового уровня снова весить коллайдеры , но я только додумался до этого

Comment: Если необходимо узнать может ли персонаж переместиться в нужные координаты можно воспользоваться проверкой Physics.CheckSphere(pos, radius, layerMask). Но на стены все равно нужно повесить коллайдер.

Answer (score 0):

Не исключаю, что существует решение без коллайдеров, но к сожалению такого не знаю.

Можете навесить на стены коллайдеры и Rigidbody. Сделать их Static. В Rigidbody в разделе Constraints проставить галочки freeze position (что бы наверняка ваши стены ни куда не делись). Ну и повесить ригидбади и коллайдер на персонажа. Теперь он не пройдет сквозь стены.
Что бы на новом уровне упростить себе жизнь - сделать префаб стены и уже расставлять префаб.

Comment: На стены Rigidbody вешать не обязательно, достаточно коллайдера на стенах.